# spark on kubernetes: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I am using spark 2.4.4. Having trouble running spark-submit on my ubuntu machine with the following config and system environment:

```
cpchung:small$ minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.17.0
  minikube v1.6.2 on Ubuntu 19.10
✨  Selecting 'kvm2' driver from user configuration (alternates: [virtualbox none])
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Using the running kvm2 "minikube" VM ...
⌛  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '18.09.9' ...
  Downloading kubelet v1.17.0
  Downloading kubeadm v1.17.0
  Pulling images ...
  Launching Kubernetes ... 
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
cpchung:small$ minikube docker-env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.39.246:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/cpchung/.minikube/certs"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
cpchung:small$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
cpchung:small$ ./run.sh
```

inside my `run.sh` is this:

```
spark-submit --class SimpleApp \
--master "k8s://https://192.168.39.246:8443" \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=somename:latest \
--conf spark.kubernetes.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
local:///small.jar
```

Then I got this:

```
simpleapp-1580791262398-driver   0/1     Error    0          21s
cpchung:small$ kubectl logs simpleapp-1580791262398-driver

20/02/04 04:41:10 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/02/04 04:41:10 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://simpleapp-1580791262398-driver-svc.default.svc:4040
20/02/04 04:41:10 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///small.jar at spark://simpleapp-1580791262398-driver-svc.default.svc:7078/jars/small.jar with timestamp 1580791270603
20/02/04 04:41:14 INFO ExecutorPodsAllocator: Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes.
20/02/04 04:41:14 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Exec Failure: HTTP 403, Status: 403 - 
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark up to `v2.4.4` uses [fabric8 Kubernetes client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) `v4.1.2` which works only with Kubernetes APIs `1.9.0 - 1.12.0`, please refer [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#compatibility-matrix) and [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml#L32).

Spark 2.4.5 will upgrade Kubernetes client to `v4.6.1` and will support Kubernetes APIs up to `1.15.2`.

So you have the following options:

- Downgrade Kubernetes cluster to `1.12`
- Wait until Spark `2.4.5/3.0.0` is released and downgrade Kubernetes cluster to `1.15.2`
- Upgrade Spark `fabric8 Kubernetes client` dependency and do custom build of Spark and its Docker image

Hope it helps.

### Update 1

In order to run Spark on Kubernetes cluster with API version `1.17.0+` you need to patch Spark code based on tag `v2.4.5` with the following changes:

```
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
index c9850ca512..41468e1363 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@
   <name>Spark Project Kubernetes</name>
   <properties>
     <sbt.project.name>kubernetes</sbt.project.name>
-    <kubernetes.client.version>4.6.1</kubernetes.client.version>
+    <kubernetes.client.version>4.7.1</kubernetes.client.version>
   </properties>
 
   <dependencies>
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
index 575bc54ffe..c180ea3a7b 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
@@ -67,7 +67,8 @@ private[spark] class BasicDriverFeatureStep(
       .withAmount(driverCpuCores)
       .build()
     val driverMemoryQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
-      .withAmount(s"${driverMemoryWithOverheadMiB}Mi")
+      .withAmount(driverMemoryWithOverheadMiB.toString)
+      .withFormat("Mi")
       .build()
     val maybeCpuLimitQuantity = driverLimitCores.map { limitCores =>
       ("cpu", new QuantityBuilder(false).withAmount(limitCores).build())
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
index d89995ba5e..9c589ace92 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
@@ -86,7 +86,8 @@ private[spark] class BasicExecutorFeatureStep(
     // executorId
     val hostname = name.substring(Math.max(0, name.length - 63))
     val executorMemoryQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
-      .withAmount(s"${executorMemoryTotal}Mi")
+      .withAmount(executorMemoryTotal.toString)
+      .withFormat("Mi")
       .build()
     val executorCpuQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
       .withAmount(executorCoresRequest)
```

`QuantityBuilder` has changed the way of parsing the input with [this PR](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/1921/files) which is available since fabric8 Kubernetes client `v4.7.0`.

### Update 2

Spark images are based on `openjdk:8-jdk-slim` which runs Java `8u252` which in order has a [bug related to OkHttp](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2145). To fix it we require fabric8 Kubernetes client `v4.9.2`, please refer its [release notes](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/releases/tag/v4.9.2) for more details.

Also the patch above can be simplified:

```
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
index c9850ca512..595aaba8dd 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@
   <name>Spark Project Kubernetes</name>
   <properties>
     <sbt.project.name>kubernetes</sbt.project.name>
-    <kubernetes.client.version>4.6.1</kubernetes.client.version>
+    <kubernetes.client.version>4.9.2</kubernetes.client.version>
   </properties>
 
   <dependencies>
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
index 575bc54ffe..a1559e07a4 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala
@@ -66,9 +66,7 @@ private[spark] class BasicDriverFeatureStep(
     val driverCpuQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
       .withAmount(driverCpuCores)
       .build()
-    val driverMemoryQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
-      .withAmount(s"${driverMemoryWithOverheadMiB}Mi")
-      .build()
+    val driverMemoryQuantity = new Quantity(s"${driverMemoryWithOverheadMiB}Mi")
     val maybeCpuLimitQuantity = driverLimitCores.map { limitCores =>
       ("cpu", new QuantityBuilder(false).withAmount(limitCores).build())
     }
diff --git a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
index d89995ba5e..b439ebf837 100644
--- a/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
+++ b/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/BasicExecutorFeatureStep.scala
@@ -85,9 +85,7 @@ private[spark] class BasicExecutorFeatureStep(
     // name as the hostname.  This preserves uniqueness since the end of name contains
     // executorId
     val hostname = name.substring(Math.max(0, name.length - 63))
-    val executorMemoryQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
-      .withAmount(s"${executorMemoryTotal}Mi")
-      .build()
+    val executorMemoryQuantity = new Quantity(s"${executorMemoryTotal}Mi")
     val executorCpuQuantity = new QuantityBuilder(false)
       .withAmount(executorCoresRequest)
       .build()
```

Comment: I am using minikube on ubuntu. Downgrade doesnt seem to be an option. Does that mean I need to reinstall minikube?

Comment: I think that you can lauch minikube with the desired kubernetes version without reinstalling it: `minikube start --kubernetes-version <desired-version>`

Comment: I have the same problem on mac using `docker-desktop`. Can I start k8s with a desired version? @Aliaksandr Sasnouskikh

Comment: @cpchung, I think the only way for you is [download](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/) the desired version of docker desktop. Or you can always switch to [Minikube](https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#specifying-the-kubernetes-version).

Comment: @AliaksandrSasnouskikh - what version of fabric8 Kubernetes client version works for spark 2.4.5 custom build? The version of k8s platform is 1.17.2.

Comment: Spark `v2.4.5` depends on [fabric8 Kubernetes client `v4.6.1`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/pom.xml#L32) which in order is compatible with Kubernetes API `v1.9.0 - v1.15.3` by the [Compatibility matrix](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#compatibility-matrix). You need `fabric8 Kubernetes client` >= `v4.7.0`.

Comment: @AliaksandrSasnouskikh - Thank you. will try to build spark v2.4.5 with fabric8 k8s client v4.7.0 and will see if it can work with k8s platform v1.17.2

Comment: @karunakar, cool. Please share the outcomes, I feel it should be valuable to the community. And of course in case of issues feel free to reach me.

Comment: @AliaksandrSasnouskikh . Definitely will do.

Comment: @AliaksandrSasnouskikh - I've built it, but it broke the functionality of memory conversion of spark to k8s yaml.

Comment: Thank you @AliaksandrSasnouskikh.