# Run Spark example on Kubernetes failed

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

- My Mac OS/X Version : 10.15.3
- Minikube Version: 1.9.2

I start the minikube use the following command without any extra configuration.

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
--image-repository='registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers' --cpus 4 --memory 4096 --alsologtostderr
```

And I download spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 from the Spark official website and build spark images by the following command

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -m -t 2.4.5 build
```

then I run Spark-pi using the follwing command within my local machine where store the Spark 2.4.5.

```
kubectl create serviceaccount spark
kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=admin --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default
./bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://192.168.99.104:8443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:2.4.5 \
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar
```

I get the following error

[image]

the full log can be found at [full log](https://github.com/hzyfox/picture-share/blob/master/logs/log.txt)

Can anyone explain this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the Kubernetes version you launched with Minikube.

Spark `v2.4.5` fabric8 Kubernetes client `v4.6.1` is compatible with Kubernetes API up to `1.15.2` (refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60052900/7947644)).

You can launch the specific Kubernetes API version with Minikube by adding `--kubernetes-version` flag to `minikube start` command (refer [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#selecting-a-kubernetes-version)).

Also the issue might be caused by OkHttp library bug described in the comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61565751/7947644) qustion.

Answer (score 0):

Another spark image (from `gcr.io/spark-operator/spark`) worked for me, without downgrading the version of Kubernetes.

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://192.168.99.100:8443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=512m \
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=512m \
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar
```

Comment: Can you verify the K8s client version bundled with that image?

Comment: Do you mean this? $ kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Nope, fabric8 (most probably it is it) jar version on the classpath.

Comment: Is this one `kubernetes-client-4.6.1.jar`? I found it in `spark/jars` directory of the pod running spark:v2.4.5 image.

Comment: Yeap, it is it. Can you please also check your K8s API version just to be sure? Or Minikube version if you do not specify the K8s version explicitly when launching minikube.

Comment: $ minikube start  
  `minikube v1.9.0` on Ubuntu 18.04  
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile  
  Retarting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...  
  Preparing `Kubernetes v1.18.0` on Docker 19.03.8 ...

I had the same problem and you are right about the version. When I tried the examples by spark-on-k8s operator and it worked. Then I changed the spark image as the example and it worked too. I do not know why.

Comment: Thx for the details, I'll try the same setup. And take it easy, I just want to help ;)

Comment: Thank you ^^. Please let me know if you find something.