# Why am I not able to run sparkPi example on a Kubernetes (K8s) cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-pod

I have a K8s cluster up and running, on VMs inside VMWare Workstation, as of now. I'm trying to deploy a Spark application natively using the official documentation from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template). However, I also landed on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-spark-from-source-and-deploy-it-to-a-kubernetes-cluster-in-60-minutes-225829b744f9?gi=b30ed2bf7f9a) article which made it clearer, I felt.

Now, earlier my setup was running inside nested VMs, basically my machine is on Win10 and I had an Ubuntu VM inside which I had 3 more VMs running for the cluster (not the best idea, I know).

When I tried to run my setup by following the article mentioned, I first created a service account inside the cluster called `spark`, then created a [clusterrolebinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) called `spark-role`, gave `edit` as the clusterrole and assigned it to the `spark` service account so that Spark driver pod has sufficient permissions.

I then try to run the example SparkPi job using this command line:

```
bin/spark-submit \
  --master k8s://https://<k8-cluster-ip>:<k8-cluster-port> \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --name spark-pi \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=kmaster:5000/spark:latest \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar 100
```

And it fails within a few seconds after it has created the **driver-pod**, it goes into **Running** state and after like 3 seconds goes into **Error** state.

On giving the command `kubectl logs spark-pi-driver` [this](https://pastebin.com/qs6UKw9k) is the log I get.

The second `Caused by:` is always either as mentioned above i.e:

- `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)` or,
- `Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException`

[Log #2](https://pastebin.com/spgfM6ie) for reference.

After running into dead-ends with this, I tried giving `--deploy-mode client` to see if it makes a difference and get more verbose logs. You can read the difference between client and cluster mode from [here](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/spark-modes-of-deployment/).

On deploying the job as **client mode** it still fails, however, now I see that each time the driver pod (now running not as a pod but as a process on the local machine) tries to create an executor pod, it goes into a loop infinitely trying to create an executor pod with a count-number appended to the pod name, as the last one goes into a terminated state. Also, now I can see the Spark UI on the 4040 port but the job doesn't move forward as it's stuck on trying to create even a single executor pod.

I get [this](https://pastebin.com/LmbA67GR) log.

To me, this makes it pretty apparent that it's a resource crunch maybe?

So to be sure, I delete the nested VMs and setup 2 new VMs on my main machine and connect them using a NAT network and setup the same K8s cluster.

But now when I try to do the exact same thing it fails with the same error (Broken Pipe/ShutdownException), except now it tells me that it fails even at **creating a driver-pod**.

[This](https://pastebin.com/sWS6vBQf) is the log for reference.

Now I can't even fetch logs as to why it fails, because it's never even created.

I've broken my head over this and can't figure out why it's failing. Now, I tried out a lot of things to rule them out but so far nothing has worked except one (which is a completely different solution).

I tried the **spark-on-k8-operator** from GCP from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) and it **worked** for me. I wasn't able to see the Spark UI as it runs briefly but it prints the Pi value in the shell window, so I know it works.
I'm guessing, that even this spark-on-k8s-operator 'internally' does the same thing but I really need to be able to deploy it natively, or at least know why it fails.

Any help here will be appreciated (I know it's a long post). Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in okhttp for jdk8, we have upgraded okhttp with fix https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/2176 . We will cut a release in coming week as soon as we can. Apologies for inconvienience caused

Comment: The issue might also be caused by the incompatibility of the fabric8 Kubernetes client and Kubernetes API of your k8s cluster. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575925/7947644) answer.

Comment: @RohanKumar I see that a version with a fix is released 4.10.0. I updated the dependency in Spark but the `Broken pipe` is still there

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes I had downgraded my open-jdk-8 version to the one just before 252 and the error where it failed to even create the driver pod was gone but the ShutdownException was still there, now with "Operation [get] for type [pod] failed.

Comment: However, @AliaksandrSasnouskikh 's comment helped. I was on K8s v1.17.4. Downgrading to v1.15.3 did the job for me! It was a compatibility issue. Thank you!

Comment: Downgrading k8s version helped me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the kubernetes version that you are deploying is compatible with the Spark version that you are using.

Apache Spark uses the Kubernetes Client library to communicate with the kubernetes cluster.

As per today the latest LTS Spark version is 2.4.5 which includes the kubernetes client version 4.6.3.

Checking the **compatibility matrix** of Kubernetes Client: [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-matrix)

The supported kubernetes versions go all the way up to v1.17.0.

Based on my personal experience **Apache Spark 2.4.5 works well with kubernetes version v1.15.3**. I have had problems with more recent versions.

When a not supported kubernetes version is used, the logs to get are as the ones you are describing:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) or,
Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException
```

Comment: Yes as mentioned earlier in a comment by @AliaksandrSasnouskikh, it was exactly this issue. Downgrading my K8s version from v1.17.4 to v1.15.3 did the job for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Faced exact same issue with v1.18.0, downgrading the version to v1.15.3 made it work

minikube start --cpus=4 --memory=4048 --kubernetes-version v1.15.3

Answer (score 0):

Spark on K8s operator example uses a Spark image (from `gcr.io`) that works. You can find the image tag in `spark-on-k8s-operator/examples/spark-pi.yaml`

```
spec:
  ...
  image: "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5"
...
```

I tried to replace the `image` config in the `bin/spark-submit` and it worked for me.

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://192.168.99.100:8443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=512m \
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=512m \
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar
```